# What could cause TFTP reloaded Cisco `running-config` on 871 to fail?

Tags: cisco, configuration, tftp

Cisco CCP *Write Configuration* borked my 871w config while I was trying to setup port forwarding.

I went through the basic steps to reconfig the router. I looked to see if I could just [reset the router](http://stubbyrouter.net/2012/02/07/howto-cisco-871-configuration-recovery/). Nope. I tested the 871's flash memory with `fsck` to see if there was hardware failure. Nope. Then I rewrote the [minimal config](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/net_mgmt/cisco_configuration_professional/guides/CiscoCPqsg.html#wp127654) for TFTP (which is the same for Cisco's CCP app.).

Thne, I successfully [uploaded](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ios-nx-os-software/ios-software-releases-122-mainline/46741-backup-config.html) [a previously working](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OBhgvcFGO0c) `running-config` from Win Vista using [SolarWinds TFTP Server](http://www.solarwinds.com/downloads/), unfortunately the restore was not entirely successful. The old running config was saved to the 871's `startup-config` and I can login using console port. Some other things that *are* working are the *hostname* and *welcome message* but that's about it.

<s>Startup shows an error `SETUP: new interface NVI0 placed in "shutdown" state after tftp`.</s> The missing light on the access point modem for ethernet link show the 871'a outside FE4 is not working.

SO...what's the possible problem with reloading a previously working config (approximately 4 months with the same config) via TFTP? Is there something I can look for on the 871 to verify the config? Or on Vista to validate the config file itself before I transfer it? Or, is this there a common TFTP issue?

---

UPDATE. I missed the instruction from [Cisco's TFTP](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ios-nx-os-software/ios-software-releases-122-mainline/46741-backup-config.html) page to delete `aaa` lines from the config (although a video from a [SuperUser user](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=51eLRz7zrf4) didn't make this point in his most excellent demo). There were several lines of this sort, I deleted them and uploaded again. However, they're back. I assume they're added automatically? [nope, see answer]

---

UPDATE 2. The reload of previous settings was successful, but this error remains. I don't even know now if it was there before or not. It seems irrelevant to the question.

Comment: First tftp to run, then copy run to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Cisco devices, if you copy a backup config from `tftp` to `running-config`, it doesn't fully replace the `running-config`, but is merged into it. This means that any settings which are not explicitly set in backup config, won't be affected in your `running-config`.

To cleanly restore your backup config, copy it from `tftp` to `startup-config` and reboot your router. This will work because when copied to `startup-config` backup config is not merged into it, but fully replaces it.

Comment: This [Cisco](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ios-nx-os-software/ios-software-releases-122-mainline/46741-backup-config.html#tftp) page refers to removing `AAA` lines for transfer to `running-config`. Is this the same for transfer to `startup-config`? Hmm. Should I test this?

Comment: You don't need to remove anything from your backup config unless you think that particular setting is incorrect and needs to be changed. That article suggests to remove `AAA` lines, because these lines set access settings which if incorrect may lock you out of your router.

Comment: Be sure to double check what config you restore to avoid any surprises.

Comment: Success! I would have never have tried that on my own.